# Error while installing firebase with npm - ERR_SSL_DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm

I am trying to install firebase but no matter what I do I keep getting this Error:

```
npm ERR! code ERR_SSL_DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC
npm ERR! errno ERR_SSL_DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC
npm ERR! Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/@firebase%2Fapp: 39732:error:1408F119:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:decryption failed or bad record mac:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:677:
```

I get this error after running `npm i firebase` or `npm i --save firebase`. It doesn't happen when I install any other package

I have tried all sorts of commands like `npm cache clear --force`, `npm config set strict-ssl false`, `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org`, no combination of them seams to fix it.
I am using npm version `8.5.4` and node version `v16.14.0`

When I run `npm config get cafile` it outputs `null`

I tried searching for what a certificate means without any success.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows, search "services" in the start menu, then check the "OpenSSH Authentication Agent" service. If the startup type is "disabled", select "automatic (delayed startup)". then restart the computer and try to install firebase. this solved my problem.

Comment: This solved issue. I tried only starting service. But not fixed. Then restarted. firebase installed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

please try this command : `npm i --save firebase -d` it helped me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try these solutions, otherwise most probably it happens due to a slow internet connection.

Comment: Try what solutions? No solutions shown. This does not seem to be an answer.